# How i can run java card applet in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javacard

I'm beginner in Java card SDK.I'm learning and also i found one simple example in github

```
public class HelloWorld extends Applet {

protected HelloWorld() {
    register();
}

public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
    new HelloWorld();
}

/**
 * @noinspection UnusedDeclaration
 */
public void process(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    short lc = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, lc);
}
```

}

I'm using Intellij IDE. My problem is that I don't know how I can configuration run/debug configuration? Simple, I want to run my app. In eclipse everything is easy, but I don't like it[image]

Thanks, everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [jCardSim](https://jcardsim.org/) and compile/link against that. That way you don't need a simulator setup. To compile for Java Card itself after debugging, you can simply setup Oracle's Java Card development environment.